# One function to consume from different queues and produce to different queues

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I would like to have the same function consuming messages from different RabbitMQ queues and then producing messages to different exchanges.

My function that handles the consuming and the producing

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> myFunction() {

    return (x) -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        return "hello world " + x;
    };
}
```

My `application.yml` looks like that:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: myFunction
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          myFunction-in-0:
            consumer:
              declareExchange: false
              bindQueue: false
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindingRoutingKey: '"myExchange.test.request"'
          myFunction-out-0:
            producer:
              declareExchange: false
              bindQueue: false
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              routingKeyExpression: '"myExchange.test.result"'
          myFunction-in-1:
            consumer:
              declareExchange: false
              bindQueue: false
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindingRoutingKey: '"myExchange1.test.request"'
          myFunction-out-1:
            producer:
              declareExchange: false
              bindQueue: false
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              routingKeyExpression: '"myExchange1.test.result"'
      bindings:
        myFunction-in-0:
          content-type: application/json
          group: MY_QUEUE
        myFunction-out-0:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: myExchange
        myFunction-in-1:
          content-type: application/json
          group: MY_QUEUE1
        myFunction-out-1:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: myExchange1
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is having one function and under the hood, I want Spring Cloud Stream to create two consumers for me and two producers without me having to change the function at all.

I thought that this is possible by changing the binding in out binding to 0 1 respectively, but it is not working. Spring cloud stream only creates one consumer for the `in-0` binding and my `in-1` binding is ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi input/output is currently (3.1.3) **only** supported with reactive functions.

> IMPORTANT: At the moment, function arity is only supported for reactive functions `(Function<TupleN<Flux<?>…​>, TupleN<Flux<?>…​>>)` centered on Complex event processing where evaluation and computation on confluence of events typically requires view into a stream of events rather than single event.

However, even with the reactive functions the definition is a bit different and the indexes are explicitly coupled with the function arity. In contrast to your example, different bindings could have different input/output types for each index. Therefore, the function definition uses `TupleN` type from Project Reactor allowing to specify the type of each binding.

Let's make your example work:

```java
@Bean
public Function<Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>, Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>> myFunction2() {
    return tuple -> {
        var flux = Flux.merge(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2())
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .map(x -> "hello world " + x)
                .publish();
        flux.connect();
        return Tuples.of(flux, flux);
    };
}
```

If you really cannot change the function, you could create a reactive wrapper function:

```java
@Bean
public Function<Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>, Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>> myFunctionWrapper() {
    return tuple -> {
        var flux = Flux.merge(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2())
                .map(myFunction())
                .publish();
        flux.connect();
        return Tuples.of(flux, flux);
    };
}
```

Here is the related section in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_arity).